# How to fetch xml image and show in UIcollectionview ? (change code for Json to XML)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xml-parsing, uicollectionview

I'm a newbie xcode programmer.

I've read a tutorial for showing collectionview using Flickr Json.
here is the two links: http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12

and

http://www.raywenderlich.com/22417/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-22

but now I want to make the collectionview for Danbooru, a site which only shows XML.

the tutorial above uses 4 author-made files, (Flickr.h, Flickr.m, FlickrPhoto.h, FlickrPhoto.m)

I think Flickr.m file does the key part in that app, so will quote that code:

```
#import "Flickr.h"
#import "FlickrPhoto.h"

#define kFlickrAPIKey @"d02c877c0a4220890f14fc95f8b16983"

@implementation Flickr

+ (NSString *)flickrSearchURLForSearchTerm:(NSString *) searchTerm
{
searchTerm = [searchTerm stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=%@&text=%@&per_page=20&format=json&nojsoncallback=1",kFlickrAPIKey,searchTerm];
}

+ (NSString *)flickrPhotoURLForFlickrPhoto:(FlickrPhoto *) flickrPhoto size:(NSString *) size
{
if(!size)
{
    size = @"m";
}
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://farm%d.staticflickr.com/%d/%lld_%@_%@.jpg",flickrPhoto.farm,flickrPhoto.server,flickrPhoto.photoID,flickrPhoto.secret,size];
}

- (void)searchFlickrForTerm:(NSString *) term completionBlock:(FlickrSearchCompletionBlock) completionBlock
{
NSString *searchURL = [Flickr flickrSearchURLForSearchTerm:term];
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *searchResultString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:searchURL]
                                                       encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                          error:&error];
    if (error != nil) {
        completionBlock(term,nil,error);
    }
    else
    {
        // Parse the JSON Response
        NSData *jsonData = [searchResultString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSDictionary *searchResultsDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                                                                          options:kNilOptions
                                                                            error:&error];
        if(error != nil)
        {
            completionBlock(term,nil,error);
        }
        else
        {
            NSString * status = searchResultsDict[@"stat"];
            if ([status isEqualToString:@"fail"]) {
                NSError * error = [[NSError alloc] initWithDomain:@"FlickrSearch" code:0 userInfo:@{NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey: searchResultsDict[@"message"]}];
                completionBlock(term, nil, error);
            } else {

                NSArray *objPhotos = searchResultsDict[@"photos"][@"photo"];
                NSMutableArray *flickrPhotos = [@[] mutableCopy];
                for(NSMutableDictionary *objPhoto in objPhotos)
                {
                    FlickrPhoto *photo = [[FlickrPhoto alloc] init];
                    photo.farm = [objPhoto[@"farm"] intValue];
                    photo.server = [objPhoto[@"server"] intValue];
                    photo.secret = objPhoto[@"secret"];
                    photo.photoID = [objPhoto[@"id"] longLongValue];

                    NSString *searchURL = [Flickr flickrPhotoURLForFlickrPhoto:photo size:@"m"];
                    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:searchURL]
                                                              options:0
                                                                error:&error];
                    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                    photo.thumbnail = image;

                    [flickrPhotos addObject:photo];
                }

                completionBlock(term,flickrPhotos,nil);
            }
        }
    }
});
}

+ (void)loadImageForPhoto:(FlickrPhoto *)flickrPhoto thumbnail:(BOOL)thumbnail completionBlock:(FlickrPhotoCompletionBlock) completionBlock
{

NSString *size = thumbnail ? @"m" : @"b";

NSString *searchURL = [Flickr flickrPhotoURLForFlickrPhoto:flickrPhoto size:size];
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:searchURL]
                                              options:0
                                                error:&error];
    if(error)
    {
        completionBlock(nil,error);
    }
    else
    {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        if([size isEqualToString:@"m"])
        {
            flickrPhoto.thumbnail = image;
        }
        else
        {
            flickrPhoto.largeImage = image;
        }
        completionBlock(image,nil);
    }

});
}



@end
```

so that was the code for Json,
and by searching, I found a way to parse XML with TBXML(opensource)

by implementing the code below in viewController on another testproject, I could see URL of image coming out on debug screen:

```
void (^tbxmlSuccessBlock)(TBXML *) = ^(TBXML * tbxml){
TBXMLElement *elemRoot = nil, *elemImage = nil ;
elemRoot = tbxml.rootXMLElement;

if(elemRoot){
    elemImage = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"post" parentElement:elemRoot];

    while(elemImage){{
        NSString *localURL = [TBXML valueOfAttributeNamed:@"file_url" forElement:elemImage];
        NSLog(@"Local : %@", localURL);

       NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:localURL]];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];


        weatherPhoto.largeImage = image;
        elemImage=elemImage->nextSibling;
    }}
}};
void (^tbxmlFailureBlock) (TBXML *, NSError *) = ^(TBXML * tbxml, NSError * error){
NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
};
- (void)parseXML{
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://safebooru.org/index.php?page=dapi&s=post&q=index&limit=5"];
[TBXML newTBXMLWithURL:imageURL success:tbxmlSuccessBlock failure:tbxmlFailureBlock];}



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];


// Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
// self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

// Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
// self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(parseXML) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

}
```

so far this is all what I got.getting URL text.
How can I change the Flickr.m and make image from XML to be shown in UIcollectionView?

Answer (score 1):

So I read your question again, and realized you asked something else. Are you asking how to make Flickr.m load an image from the XML? you don't. This class is meant to load flickr photos. You need to write your own class, that knows how to extract the url from the XML and load the image using the example I gave you.

---

You need to create a UIImage instance and load it asynchronously.
For example:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:self.URL];
    self.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (self.image)
            [self setupImageView];
    });
```

You can also use NSOperationQueue or NSURLConnection to perform async data loading.